# Como posso comparar uma password da minha DB com a do php

Tags: mysql, php-7

Eu estou a fazer o login para o meu website mas quando uso uma `query` para retirar a password da DB ela vem num hash e a minha duvida e como eu posso dar hash da passoword que o utilizador colocou e comprarala com a da DB? Para registrar a password eu utilizei a seguinte codigo `PASSWORD(password_inserida_pelo_utilizador)` do `MYSQL`.

O meu codigo para a parte de login:

```
    if ($verified === "false") {
        $link = mysqli_connect($Host, $UserName, $Password, $DataBaseName);

        $query = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '{$username}'";
        $result = $link->query($query);

        $query_password = array();

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          array_push($query_password, $row);

          print_r($query_password);

        } else {
          if ($DEBUG === True) {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $link->error;

            $verified = "true";
            $usernameLoginErr = "Username is incorrect";
          } else {
            $verified = "true";
            $usernameLoginErr = "Username is incorrect";
          }
        }

        $link->close();
    }
  }
```

Nota: No caso de existir uma forma mais segura de encryptar as passwords estou sempre aberto a novas opções.

Comment: Por que seu password(`$query_password`) é um array já que o resultado de `password_hash` é um string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu nunca recomendaria usar o `PASSWORD`, assim como não recomendo usar qualquer função criptográfica do MySQL, quase todas elas são extremamente problemáticas (como o `AES_ENCRYPT`, `DES_ENCRYPT`, `ENCRYPT`...). Só para ter ideia, o MySQL usa o AES-ECB por padrão para o `AES_ENCRYPT`, [e você consegue ver o penguin](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/).

O `PASSWORD()` sempre gera o mesmo resultado, então bastaria fazer:

```
$query = "SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '{$username}' AND Password = PASSWORD({$password})";
```

---

Sobre as melhores maneira, o melhor é usar o Argon2ID, disponível no PHP 7.3. Para isso, utilize o [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Existem outros tópicos no SO sobre quais são os melhores algoritmos de derivação de senha. Além do Argon2, existem também o PBKDF2, BCrypt, Script e Lyra2. O PHP tem suporte para o Argon2, BCrypt, PBKDF2.